# How to Add Extra Search terms with Wordpress Search keyword term?

Tags: php

Using the default WordPress search box, when we search for a term, it will result the URL as follows.

Search term: hello
URL: `yourdomain.com/?s=hello`

I want to add some extra text after the search term URL whenever someone make a search.

eg, if the Search term is *"hello"*, the search URL should be

`yourdomain.com/?s=hello&post_type=product`

What code should I add to make these changes?

Comment: Is the user inputting the value "product" that is appended to the query string?  Where is that value coming from?

Comment: No I want to automatically append the string "&post_type=product" with all the search terms a user search.

Comment: Ok, if it's automatic then the correct approach is the following method, where you create a new `searchform.php` for the theme, you can see the instructions here: https://wpmudev.com/blog/build-your-own-custom-wordpress-search/

Comment: OK Thanks.. Will Have a look.